# Codeigniter Upload Class MIME issue

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I'm trying to upload an image using the CodeIgniter Upload Class.  This has been working up until a few days ago when I noticed that uploading only certain images were causing issues.  Currently I'm testing the issue with an image named "image.jpg".  Per the file extension, the image is a JPG image which should return a mime type of "image/jpeg".  However, for some reason, when uploading this image, the errors returned state.

> "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

My config is rather simple and allows for a few different image types, including JPGs.

```
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'file_name'     => $full,
        'upload_path'   => $path,
        'max_size'      => 5120
    );
```

The real kicker here is when I echo out the `$this->upload->data()` which returns:

```
    Array
    (
        [file_name] => image.jpg
        [file_type] => image/png
        [file_path] => /var/www/tmp/
        [full_path] => /var/www/tmp/image.jpg
        [raw_name] => image
        [orig_name] => 
        [client_name] => image.jpg
        [file_ext] => .jpg
        [file_size] => 50519
        [is_image] => 1
        [image_width] => 
        [image_height] => 
        [image_type] => 
        [image_size_str] => 
    )
```

Does someone know why the image is returning a file_type of `image/png` when the image should be returning `image/jpeg`?

I've checked the `config/mimes.php` but everything appears to be correct and in order.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

If I set the allowed types to: `allowed_types => '*'` it seems to work, but I do not want to allow all file types.  This was an issue prior to CodeIgniter 2.0.  The version I'm currently running is 2.1.3, so the fixes for 2.0 are not relevant as this was supposedly "fixed" in current versions.

Comment: I further checked the image by uploading it to a MIME detection website just to make sure it wasn't corrupt, etc. and it was returning the correct "image/jpeg" MIME on the detection site.  So somewhere in the CI Upload Library, it is not detecting the correct mime type.

Answer (score 0):

After doing much research on this issue and not finding any answers, I debugged the situation myself; completely.  Turns out the MIME type being returned wrong is actually correct; I'm assuming.  The original image file was created as a PNG but re-created improperly somewhere else.  Using the PHP : FINFO : function to check true file_type's against signatures, etc. is why it was returning PNG and not JPG.  I'm assuming this helps prevent people from creating fake image files and uploading them to servers as the $_FILES[filename][file_type] is not entirely accurate.  This helps prevent them from creating, for instance, a .php file with code inside and renaming and uploading that file as a .jpg.

Hopefully this all makes sense and helps someone out who thinks they have a similar issue.